# Designing a complex SQL structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

I have to design a pretty complicated SQL structure.

I'm making a product distribution panel, where you can order e-cigarette liquids from a company.

Each liquid has it's own volume, nicotine in miligrams, name and brand.
I want to make the administration panel easy to use. Admin would just add a product with a name and a brand, and then add volumes, and power(nicotine).

I was thinking about making a main table with products (brand and name), and then tables with volume and power, but it's a really bad idea, when I think about it... Also making a column in a table for power, and then making a set of powers a string, like 10mg, 20mg, 18mg would be a mistake.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the new requirements I think it would be better to have the db schema as described on the picture.

[image: DB SCHEMA]

You have `products` table and `volumes`, `powers` and `nicotine` tables.
If a product from `product` table has either volume, power or nicotine, then in the corresponding table there is a record with the relevant product_id.

One brand may have many products, every product may have or may not have nicotine, power or volume property. For instance if a product has `nicotine` property, then in `nicotine` table there is a record with this `product_id`. If not, the `nicotine` table will not contain the record with this `product_id`. The same rule applies to `powers` and `volumes`.

Comment: Hmm, I have like only 5 brands, but dozens of products in each brand, is it  still a good structure?

Comment: Is it possible that you will add new brands in the future?

Comment: Would it be worse, if I just make one table with brand name product name, product id, nicotine and volume?

Comment: Yes, actually but there will be maximally 5 or 6 brands

Comment: Yes, it would be worse, because you will need to duplicate brand name for every product you have in that table.

Comment: So, as you are going to add new brands in the future, then it is important to have`brands` table. Do you have more fields and requirements than you described in your question ?

Comment: Hmm no I don't think so but there is one thing, should I like make another table if I want to add another type of product? for example, a e-cigarette won't have a power, and volume, but batery capacity?

Comment: That what I was asked for :) New requirements. Let's talk on chat.

Comment: Or should i make a TYPE column and instead of volume and power, do like option1, option2, and in e-cigarette that would be batery capacity, but in a liquid it would be a volume?

Comment: SO writes that it can't start chat session. Please wait, and I will update my answer according to new requirements.

Comment: Just for clarification: are the following product properties persistent? For instance, for a person, `age` is a persistent property, because every man has age. If I understand you right, `power` and `volume` are not persistent. A product can have these properties, but it can be without these properties. Is `nicotine` property persistent for the product?

Comment: Not only will the brands have multiple products, but one product could have many volumes, so there will be the same products with different volumes and powers like:
Mild XYZ 10ML 18MG, and then Mild XYZ 20ML 25MG. It's not persistent [Mild is the brand, XYZ is the name, ML is the volume, and MG is the power]

Comment: Get it. Please wait couple of minutes, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński if you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I now understand everything but you misunderstood me. Nicotine IS the power :)

Comment: One more question, doeas the gray key on the gram mean it's a unique key?

Comment: @MateuszSowiński are you talking about `brand_id` in `products` table? `brand_id` is unique in `brands` table to identify the brand by its id. In `products` table different records may have the same `brand_id` as relation between `brands` and `products` is one-to-many.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński note start and end of every line which connects tables. These lines show the relation between tables. For example, look at line that connects `products` and `volumes`. It is one-to-many relation line. Because `one` product can have `many` volumes.